# Add default choices manually

Tags: forms, symfony

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('agency', EntityType::class, [
            'placeholder' => "select agency",
            "choice_label" => "getName",
            "class" => Agency::class,
            "label" => "Associée à l'agence",
            "required" => false,
        ]);
}
```

How can add default choices manually for exemple :

```
// agencies from DB
agancy1
agency2
agency3
test // add test manually
```

Comment: It wouldn't make sense for `EntityType`, because choices (ids actually) must be able to be casted to your`Agency` entity. If you put there any other value, it will fail.

Comment: I'm agree with Jakub Matczak. Look at [ChoiceType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) instead.